# C# code for getting XML element by certain attribute value

Tags: c#, xml

I am creating XML document by reading some objects and adding them to proper place (inside xml tree structure). To be able to add it to proper place I need parent XmlNode so I could call `parentNode.AppendChild(node);`

How can I get `XmlNode` object if I know value of one of its attributes?

```
XmlDocument dom = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode parentNode = null;
XmlNode node = dom.CreateElement(item.Title); //item is object that I am writing to xml

XmlAttribute nodeTcmUri = dom.CreateAttribute("tcmUri");
nodeTcmUri.Value = item.Id.ToString();
node.Attributes.Append(nodeTcmUri);
parentNode = ??? - how to get XML node if I know its "tcmUri" attribute value (it is unique value, no other node has same "tcmUri" attribute value)
```

Comment: For complicated XML queries, you should consider using [XPath](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333/en-us).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using SelectSingleNode function and xpath query as below

```
XmlNode parentNode = dom.SelectSingleNode("descendant::yournodename[@tcmUri='" + item.Id.ToString() + "']");
```

Where `yournodename` has to be replaced with the node name of the parent elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(content);
XmlNodeList  list = doc.SelectNodes("mynode");
 foreach (XmlNode item in list)
                {
                    if (item.Attributes["tcmUri"].Value == some_value)
                    {
                         // do what you want, item is the element you are looking for
                     }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
var nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("<Node Name>[@tcmUri = \"<Value>\"]");
if(list.Count>0)
 parentNode = list[0];
```

Replace `<Node Name>` with the node name which you want to make the parent node.
Replace the `<Value>` with the value of tcmUri attribute of the Node which you want to make the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

XPath is your friend :

```
string xpath = String.Format("//parentTag[@tcmUri='{0}']", "tcmUriValueHere");
//or in case parent node name (parentTag) may varies
//you can use XPath wildcard:
//string xpath = String.Format("//*[@tcmUri='{0}']", "tcmUriValueHere");
parentNode = dom.SelectSingleNode(xpath)
```

Comment: @Thanks. I wasn't yet using XPath, its really useful in situations like this one.